# Import DER encoded public key using crypto API

Tags: windows, rsa, public-key, cryptoapi, der

Is it possible to import DER encoded public key using MS crypto API? So i can verfiy signatures ?
I need a piece of code or help for MS Crypto API for importing DER encoded public-key/certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Following three steps will allow you to import your public key certificate

1. Get the certificate context using [CertCreateCertificateContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa376033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. Open the other people certificate store with [CertOpenStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa376559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for ADDRESSBOOK
3. Add the certificate context to the other people certificate store using [CertAddCertificateContextToStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)