# Import public key using Windows C CNG/Crypto API

Tags: c, windows, cryptography, cryptoapi, cng

I need to verify a signature on multiple platforms, say Windows and Linux. 
I am open to any public key format as long as I can write a platform-specific C code that can verify this signature using the provided public key (the same public key for all platforms).

It looks to me that PKCS#1 ASN.1 DER format is the most standard one, so I assume I should use it for the public key ([this article](https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2011-05-08-converting-openssh-public-keys/) provides some introduction on possible formats).

My problem is importing this public key in Windows. 
It looks like this is supported in C# (e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103752/1847482)), but I couldn't find any Windows C/C++ function that can read a public key in PKCS#1 ASN.1 DER or PEM format and convert it to its BLOB structure, probably I didn't search good enough.

A [similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877325/import-der-encoded-public-key-using-crypto-api) seems to be talking about certificates, while I just need to deal with a bare public key.

**Is there any CNG or CryptoAPI function that could read this (or other) format and convert it to either [DSA BLOB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_dsa_key_blob#remarks) or [RSA BLOB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_rsakey_blob#remarks) structure?** 
 (If given a choice, I'd prefer to use [CNG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/typical-cng-programming) functions instead of CryptoAPI deprecated ones).

Comment: Typically if people want to use crypto functions on multiple platforms they use OpenSSL/LibreSSL library, especially if the key should not be saved in the platform specific key management systems (Windows certificate store, Gnome Keyring, ..).

Comment: We produce a library that creates a response with a signing and the client projects are expected to verify the signature. So I wanted to require as little as possible from the client projects' code. But you've made a very valid point, maybe requiring OpenSSL is reasonable, I'll check. Thank you.